# SCHED_FIFO thread freezes terminal

Tags: c++, pthreads, scheduler

I have a centos minimal hexacore 3.5ghz machine and I do not undestand why a SCHED_FIFO realtime thread pinned to 1 core only, freezes the terminal? How to avoid this while keeping the realtime behaviour of the thread without using sleep in the loop or blocking it? To simplify my problem, this thread tries to dequeuue items from a non-blocking,lockfree,concurrent queue in an infinite loop.
     The kernel runs on core 0, all the other cores are free. All other threads and my process too, are SCHED_OTHER same priority, 20. This is the only thread where i need ultra low latency for some high frequency calculations. After starting the application it seems everything works ok but my terminal freezes (i connect remotely trough ssh). I am able to see the threads created and force close my app from htop. The RT thread seems to run 100% burnout the core assigned as expected. When i kill the app, the terminal frozen is released and i can use again.
       It looks like that thread has higher priorty than everything else across all cores, but i want this on the core i pinned it only.

Thank you

Comment: So just the terminal freezes, but not the machine as a whole? Which process, exactly, is no longer reacting? The shell? `sshd`? (The terminal is the program you run locally on your computer, so if that indeed freezes, it can't be related to the scheduling priority.)

Comment: Hello Florian, that sshd session freezes. I can create a new session and kill the process or use the machine. Also my project seems to work properly behind that frozen session.

Comment: if i create another session and start htop i see sshd: root@pts/0 with process status D for the frozen session..

Comment: The next step would be to attach a debugger to the process and figure out where `sshd` is blocking. You can also get kernel backtrace with the the `t` and `w` sysrq keys (via `/proc/sysrq-trigger` if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Hi victor you need to isolate the core from the linux scheduler so that it does not try to assign lower priority tasks such as running your terminal to a core that is running SCHED_* jobs with higher priority.  You can achieve isolating core 1 in your case by adding the kernel option isolcpus=1 to your grub.cfg (or whatever boot loader config you are using).

After rebooting you can confirm that you have successfully isolated core 1 by running dmesg | grep isol
and see that your kernel was booted with the option.

Here is some more info on isolcpus:
https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re46.html

Comment: I should add that the effect of isolating cores is that the linux scheduler will not use those cores for any tasks that aren't otherwise assigned programmatically via sched_set_affinity or via taskset.